# How to improve my codes to implement 'return false'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to return false after a conditional statement fail.

I have

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('.title').each(function() {
        if (id == $(this).attr('id')) {
            alert('The name already exists.')
            return false; //I hope my codes would stop here if condition is true
        }
    })
    // my codes still call the doSomething function even if the conditional         
    //statement is true
    doSomething();
})​
```

I want do call the `doSomething` function ONLY if `id != $(this).attr('id).`

The codes below gave me what I want but it seems ugly.

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    var nameExist = false
    $('.title').each(function() {
        if (id == $(this).attr('id')) {
            alert('The name already exists.')
            nameExist = true;
            return false; //I hope my codes would stop here if condition is true
        }
    })
    if (!nameExist) {
        doSomething();
    }
})​
```

Anyone has a better approach for this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use break - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break

Comment: I do not see your point. The `doSomething()` method is out of the function block. As a result it has nothing to do with what happens in the function.

Comment: You're returning false from the anonymous function in $.each, not returning false from your anonymous function in $.click

Comment: @JayBlanchard: break won't stop a jQuery each function call

Comment: @JayBlanchard `break` doesn't make `each` stop iterate. return false do it. `Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration.`

Comment: +1 to all since all answers apply to my questoin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You don't need to iterate thrue the elements**, you can get it by the id and class like, `#myId.myClass`.

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    if($('#' + id + '.title').length) {
        alert('The name already exists.');
    } else {
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

Comment: I think only thing wrong with this solution is `doSomething()` should be in the else :)

Answer (score 4):

Switch to a basic for loop.

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    var elements = $(".title");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (id == elements[i].id) {
            alert('The name already exists.')
            return false; //I hope my codes would stop here if condition is true
        }
    }

    doSomething();
})​
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind not exiting the loop early, you can use jQuery `filter`

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var itensWithSameName = $('.title').filter(function(){
      return id == $(this).attr('id');
    })

    if(itensWithSameName.size() > 0)
        alert('The name already exists.');
});
```

Comment: +1; it's always better to state the conditions for usability.

Comment: replace `.size()` with `.length` please, :)

Comment: @KevinB: both size and length can be used. Since it's outside the loop, there's no performance penalty for the extra method call. It's a matter of personal preference (although I usually use `.length` on my production code)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you have is fine, but this avoids the extra conditional:

```
var func = doSomething;
...
if (id == $(this).attr('id')) {
   func = $.noop;
...

func();
```

Comment: `$(this).attr('id')` ==> `this.id`

Comment: Not sure if this is clean. It smells with self-rewriting code. The code is also not written in chronological order.